# A Sperner-like bound

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Let $x_1,\cdots , x_n$ be a sequence of real number such that $x_i\geq 1$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, $S=\{\alpha_1x_1+\cdots +\alpha_nx_n | \alpha_i\in\{0,+1,-1\}\}$ and $I=[a,b)$ be a Interval with length $2$. Show that
$$\displaystyle |I\cap S|\leq\dbinom{n}{\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor}$$
This looks like something to do with [Sperner's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem) but not sure. This was given me by a friend, he has proved it, but wants another proof. I couldn't do it, so I seek help. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Are you sure you want to allow -1? I think it is false with that, but true otherwise

Comment: Can you prove it without $-1$, and a counterexample for that case would be welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Just take $1,1.5$ and it already fails for $n=2$, $I = [0,2)$. It is not so hard to extend this to general $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1 , \ldots , x_n \in \mathbb{R}$, all bigger than 1. Let $$S = \{\alpha_1 x_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n x_n : \alpha_i \in \{-1,1\}\}.$$ Then $$|S \cap I| \leq \dbinom{n}{\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor}.$$

(Pf) This follows from Sperner theorem and the following claim.

Claim: Let $J_1  \ldots , J_k \subset \{1, \ldots , n\}$ be index sets such that for all $1 \leq i \leq k$, $$\sum_{j \in J_i} x_j - \sum_{j \in \overline{J_i}} x_j  \in I.$$ Then $J_1  \ldots , J_k $ is an antichain.

(Pf) Suppose $J_1 \subset J_2$. Then, using that $x_i \geq 1$, we have $$\sum_{j \in J_2} x_j - \sum_{j \in \overline{J_2}} x_j-( \sum_{j \in J_1} x_j - \sum_{j \in \overline{J_1}} x_j) \geq 2.$$

The same (maybe more natural) proof goes through for $\{0,1\}$ if the interval is replaced by 1 (instead of 2).